# How to add an alphabet at the end of each line and should increment it for the next line and so on

Tags: perl

I have the code as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $inputfile = "file1.txt"; 
open FH,$inputfile;          

my @results = <FH>;  

close FH;           
print "\n---------type n--------------\n" ;
foreach my $line (@results) {
           if($line =~ m/(^Mgn\d\.qna.*)/i)            

                   {
                          print "$1\n";  
           }
        }
print "\n---------type p--------------\n" ;
foreach my $line (@results) {
           if($line =~ m/(^Mgp\d\.qpa.*)/i)     
                 print "$1\n"; 
          }
      }
```

output: from the above script

> ---------type n--------------
>
> Mg1.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4
>   $$UNI
>
> Mg3.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=8
>   $$UNI
>
> Mg5.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=6
>   $$UNI
>
> Mg7.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4
>   $$UNI
>
> Mg9.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03
>   mult=34 $$UNI
>
> ---------type p--------------
>
> Mg2.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=6
>   $$UNI
>
> Mg4.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=4
>   $$UNI
>
> Mg6.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=8
>   $$UNI
>
> Mg8.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03
>   mult=34 $$UNI
>
> I need output as folllows
>
> ---------type n--------------
>
> Mg1.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4
>   $$UNI a
>
> Mg3.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=8
>   $$UNI b
>
> Mg5.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=6
>   $$UNI c
>
> Mg7.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4
>   $$UNI d
>
> Mg9.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03
>   mult=34 $$UNI e
>
> ---------type p--------------
>
> Mg2.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=6
>   $$UNI f
>
> Mg4.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=4
>   $$UNI g
>
> Mg6.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=8
>   $$UNI h
>
> Mg8.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03
>   mult=34 $$UNI i

Comment: Please format this post (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: It would be nice if you posted code that actually compiles. If you want us to help you, then help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Made the code compile. Fixed your problem. Introduced a few modern Perl idioms.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $inputfile = 'file1.txt';

open my $infh, '<', $inputfile or die "Can't open $inputfile: $!\n";          

my (@type_n, @type_p);

while (<$infh>) {
   push @type_n, $_ if /(^Mgn\d\.qna.*)/i;
   push @type_p, $_ if /(^Mgp\d\.qpa.*)/i;
}

close $infh;

my $chr = 'a';

print "\n---------type n--------------\n" ;
foreach (@type_n) {
  print "$_ " . $chr++ . "\n";  
}

print "\n---------type p--------------\n" ;
foreach (@type_p) {
  print "$_ " . $chr++ . "\n";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0; #at the top of your loop.


# print this at the end of each line.
# it cycles through the letters and then goes back to a using % (modulus)
print chr(ord('a') + ( $counter % 26));
```

Comment: Seems a shame not to use Perl's magic character increment feature here: perl -E'$x = "a"; print $x++ for 1 .. 26'

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address all of the issues that you might need to consider, but here is a different way to think about your script:

```
my @regexes = (
    qr/(...)/,
    qr/(...)/,
);

for my $r (@regexes){
    my $letter = 'a';
    my @matches = map { $_ =~ $r ? $1 : () } @results;
    print join(' ', $_, $letter ++), "\n" for @matches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like that..

```
bash-3.2$ cat /tmp/$$
Mg1.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4 $$UNI
Mg3.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=8 $$UNI
Mg5.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=6 $$UNI
Mg7.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4 $$UNI
Mg9.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=34 $$UNI
Mg2.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=6 $$UNI
Mg4.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=4 $$UNI
Mg6.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=8 $$UNI
Mg8.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=34 $$UNI

bash-3.2$ perl -lne 'BEGIN{$val=a} print "$_", " $val"; ++$val'  /tmp/$$
Mg1.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4 $$UNI a
Mg3.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=8 $$UNI b
Mg5.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=6 $$UNI c
Mg7.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4 $$UNI d
Mg9.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=34 $$UNI e
Mg2.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=6 $$UNI f
Mg4.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=4 $$UNI g
Mg6.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=8 $$UNI h
Mg8.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=34 $$UNI i
```